# I am not getting post values from form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form in codeigniter which is as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>login/admin_login" method="post">
<?php //echo form_open('login/admin_login'); // This is also not working?>
    <div class="form-group">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="center">
        <a href="#" class="pull-xs-right">
          <small>Forgot?</small>
        </a>
            </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
      <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Login', 'class'=>'btn  btn-azure']); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my controller is like this:

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {

  public function admin_login()
  {
    print_r($_POST); die();

   }
}
?>
```

I have properly assigned the base url. For more information, it is like, `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ims/codeigniter/';`. When I submit the form, the url changes to destination controller, but it is loading the same form. when I reload the page with the url(after submitting form), an empty array is returned. It is not returning the values that is submitted by the form. Why is this so? Where I am doing mistake. I have cross checked the form destination controller y inspecting the elements, where I am doing mistakes?

Comment: Should you not use the input helpers?  I thought code igniter destroyed at least the GET super global.

Comment: That should not ne the issue, in my opinion. It is working fine in other places. I have tested that.

Comment: try `base_url()` instead of `site_url()` and use `exit;` instead of `die()`

Comment: Have you removed `index.php` from your url . If not change your `action` to `<?php echo site_url()?>index.php/login/admin_login`

Answer (score 0):

*Use CI form either Html Form*

Change this

```
<?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Login', 'class'=>'btn  btn-azure']); ?>
```

to this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class= "btn  btn-azure">
```

---

> **Make sure your project works without `index.php` in URL. (`action="<?php echo site_url()?>index.php/login/admin_login`)**

Comment: I also tried input type. Yes, I have removed index.php. But still it is not working. When I submit the form, the url is redirecting to correct controller and method, but not loading the content of controller. And When I refresh that url, it is returning an empty array.

Comment: @Amit, what do you mean redirecting?  If there are any http redirects, $_POST will be empty.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I agree with your point. The problem is that when form is submitted, it is going to the exact controller/method, but it is not loading the content of that method.

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating on that submit button code so do use this to check if it is really setting up the required fields or not, just for a check.

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {

  public function admin_login(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        print_r($_POST); die();
    }else{
        echo 'use input tags!';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that when submit button is clicked, the url is redirected to the right controller/method, but it does not load the content of the method. Even I am printing "Hi" in the controller. I have tried ur suggestions, it is not loading the content of the method.